# HTTPLibrary.HTTP's GET call to a URL from Robot Framework timing out

Tags: proxy, get, robotframework

I am using HTTPLibrary.HTTP's GET call to a URL from Robot Framework. This keeps timing out. I think it is a proxy issue (I want this to work on my company's intranet). Is there a way to configure proxies for this call (A company internal website opens up just fine)? Or some other libraries I could use?
Code:

```
Library              HttpLibrary.HTTP
*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    GET          http://www.thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/ #example wesbite
```

Thanks,
srivikas

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [robotframework-requests](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests) that provides an example with a proxy in its README. Here is an excerpt:

```
${proxies}=    Create Dictionary    http=http://acme.com:912    https=http://acme.com:913 |
Create Session    github    http://api.github.com    proxies=${proxies}
${resp}=    Get Request    google
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${resp.status_code}    200
```